# Is metric in GR invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, invariants

In SR, the central theme is the invariance of Lorentz metric, but under a particular Lorentz transformation.

In GR, a metric is a solution to the Einstein’s field equation and there can be all kinds of coordinate transformations.

My question is: is the metric in GR, like the Schwarzschild metric, invariant under all types, or any type, of coordinate transformation?

By invariance of metric I mean the invariance of the literal value of metric since a metric is a tensor that should ultimately yield a real number. This is not about form invariance, but the invariance in literal value.

I am asking this question because I don’t hear people talking about metric invariance in GR nor seeing application of metric invariance in GR.

Comment: The theory should be invariant under local transformations but that does not mean that the values of the field will be.  This is not true of E&M, it is Lorentz invariant (globally on Minkowski space) yet different observers will "see" different E and M fields.

Comment: @ggcg it will be invariant (or covariant) if you look at $F_{\mu \nu}$ (or the $A_{\mu}$ potential) rather than the E and M fields

Comment: @ggcg, By "The theory" you mean the  Einstein field equation that takes tensorial form? But a tensor should be invariant under coordinate transformation, right?

Comment: @lurscher, the coefficients field tensor $F$ will not be the same in different frames.

Answer (score 3):

General relativity is based on general principle of relativity, that local laws of physics are the same for all observers. This is expressed mathematically in the principle of general covariance (not invariance) which says that physical laws are expressed in terms of tensors. A tensor is a generalisation of a vector. Covariance means that, like a vector, a tensor is the same for all observers, but its description is different for different observers (for example directions like left, right forward, backward depend on which way you are facing, but the direction you are facing does not alter the motion of a car).

The metric in general relativity is a tensor. It is covariant. It can be represented as a a matrix whose values do change with coordinate transformation. However, physical quantities (like the mass, or the length of a stick) calculated from the metric are invariant.

Comment: I see your point on covariance vs invariance. But if the metric value can change with coordinate change, how can you still be sure the physical quantities expressed in the Einstein field equation are invariant under coordinate change?

Comment: There is a whole mathematical apparatus to ensure that this is so. Basically, whatever change you make to the coordinate system, the opposite change is made to components, so that the changes cancel out in answers.

Comment: Looking at the Schwarzschild metric, it is clear to me there is very little room for coordinate change that won't invalidate the metric as a solution to the Einstein field equation. It seems to me all the coordinate transformations in GR are about the effort to reach a metric solution to EFE and when that is done there is little or no room for coordinate transformation on metric - and this is one way to make the value of metric invariant.

Comment: Coordinates are arbitrary. There are numerous ways to change coordinates of Schwarzschild geometry. Here is a list of common ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Alternative_coordinates. We choose particular coordinates in order to solve Einstein's equation, and then we may transform to whatever coordinates we think may give insight. Coordinate transformation cannot invalidate a covariant equation. That is the meaning of covariance.

Comment: But they are different metric and under different assumptions. When I said little room for coordinate transformation on Schwarzschild metric, I mean like doing a Lorentz transformation which will destroy the metric as a valid solution to the Einstein field equation.

Comment: No. They are all the same metric, the same geometry, expressed in different coordinates. This is much more general than Lorentz transformation which applies only to Minkowski coordinates in flat spacetime.

Comment: I see. The Lorentz transformation is a bad idea since spacetime is curved. I think coordinate transformations within the same geometry makes sense. But still, given there can be infinitely many types of coordinate transformations, why there are only so few of them - that is, why these allowed coordinate transformations form a functional space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106925/discussion-between-charles-francis-and-southwind).